# ESP32-WROOVER randomly reboot with different reasons

Tags: arduino, esp32

Hardware:
Board: ESP32 Dev Module, node32, ttgo
Core Installation version: not sure
IDE name: Arduino IDE
Flash Frequency: 40Mhz
PSRAM enabled: not
Upload Speed: 115200
Computer OS: Windows 10

Hi,

I am working on a project, which is to use GSM to connect MQTT, and send instant data such as temperature, CO2 to MQTT server. My part functions are MQTT connecting, keep heartbeat, auto-reconnect, push message in queue and send out when connected, etc. My part works totally fine when just connect to USB Port. My partner's part functions are I/O reading, controlling, calculating, and invoking my part to send messages(BTW, my part to him has only couple of functions, config(), IoTLoop(), publishMessage(), he will invoke config() in setup(), and invoke my IoTLoop() in his loop()). When combine our parts together, it also works fine(not crashing, MQTT messages been sent) when connecting to USB port. But once we plug the board(we are using LILYGO dev board, which has ESP32-WROOVER and SIM800 in one board) to a "docker"(it connects I/O control and UART to other component, such as sensors, and a LCD), it will crash randomly. The crash reasons are different, I am posting some crash log here:

#1
Guru Meditati_on Error: Core 1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
Debug exception reason: /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:2331 (pcTaskGetTaskName)- assert failed!
abort() was called at PC 0x400893ca on core 1

Backtrace: 0x4008bca4:0x3ffccfb0 0x4008bed5:0x3ffccfd0 0x400893ca:0x3ffccff0 0x4008bfb4:0x3ffcd010 0x400847ad:0x3ffcd050

#2
Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 0 register dump:
PC : 0x401013bd PS : 0x00060c30 A0 : 0x800ffa83 A1 : 0x3ffb5580
A2 : 0x4c0c3d0c A3 : 0x00000000 A4 : 0x1a9f2520 A5 : 0x00080000
A6 : 0x43422c5e A7 : 0x00000000 A8 : 0x801013b8 A9 : 0x3ffb5560
A10 : 0x401004b4 A11 : 0x40003564 A12 : 0x0000000b A13 : 0x00000007
A14 : 0x00000000 A15 : 0x00000060 SAR : 0x0000001b EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x1a9f2520 LBEG : 0x4000c46c LEND : 0x4000c477 LCOUNT : 0x00000000

Backtrace: 0x401013bd:0x3ffb5580 0x400ffa80:0x3ffb55b0 0x400ffebc:0x3ffb55d0 0x400f9a98:0x3ffb5690 0x400f9b61:0x3ffb56c0 0x40110d45:0x3ffb56f0 0x40159201:0x3ffb5720 0x4015961b:0x3ffb5740 0x4015c5f5:0x3ffb5760 0x4015c681:0x3ffb5780 0x4008f96d:0x3ffb57a0 0x40088f49:0x3ffb57e0

#3
Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)
Core 1 register dump:
PC : 0x4000c271 PS : 0x00060034 A0 : 0x80089b37 A1 : 0x3ffd3a90
A2 : 0x3ffcbdb4 A3 : 0x3f40dbb4 A4 : 0x00000014 A5 : 0x3ffbe790
A6 : 0x3ffbe7d8 A7 : 0x00000001 A8 : 0x00000001 A9 : 0x3f40dbb5
A10 : 0x000000a5 A11 : 0x00000000 A12 : 0x8008a75b A13 : 0x3ffbe760
A14 : 0x00000008 A15 : 0x00000001 SAR : 0x0000001a EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000 LBEG : 0x4000c2e0 LEND : 0x4000c2f6 LCOUNT : 0x00000000

Backtrace: 0x4000c271:0x3ffd3a90 0x40089b34:0x3ffd3ab0 0x4008b794:0x3ffd3ad0 0x4008b74a:0x00000000

Core 0 register dump:
PC : 0x4016126e PS : 0x00060634 A0 : 0x800fa256 A1 : 0x3ffbc140
A2 : 0x00000000 A3 : 0x00000001 A4 : 0x00000000 A5 : 0x00000001
A6 : 0x00060120 A7 : 0x00000000 A8 : 0x800f913a A9 : 0x3ffbc110
A10 : 0x00000000 A11 : 0x00000001 A12 : 0x8008915c A13 : 0x3ffbc040
A14 : 0x00000000 A15 : 0x3ffbbe40 SAR : 0x00000000 EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000 LBEG : 0x00000000 LEND : 0x00000000 LCOUNT : 0x00000000

Backtrace: 0x4016126e:0x3ffbc140 0x400fa253:0x3ffbc160 0x4008a749:0x3ffbc180 0x40088f49:0x3ffbc1a0_

I used EspExceptionDecoder to try to see details, it looks like the Stack memory was messed because some times the assert point to a simple line code such as assigning value to a int variable, or a function returning point. I googled a lot about ESP stack memory, and tried to increase arduino loop task stack to 3x8192/4x8192, it look like relieved a little, but still crash. But if IoTLoop() is not invoked, it will not crash. (PS. The job of IoTLoop() is to connect MQTT via SIM800, maintain online, send out messages that are in queue, etc.) Sorry the codes are big(ten thousands of lines) and I don't know where the issue could happen so couldn't post here. Sorry if I couldn't express myself clearly. We are stuck here for couple of days. Kindly could anyone help to give some hint what could be the reason? Thanks a lot!

build info:
Sketch uses 425861 bytes (32%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 30132 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory, leaving 297548 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.

Comment: Now I tried to clean my code to replace Strings with char* as much as I can in the code, rebuild the load and upload to board, now it crashes with the following error:

Answer (score 0):

I had similar exception on my esp32, using freertos, in my case it was a stack overflow, I was not allocating enough memory to a freertos task and I tried to use a huge object and it crashed.
Those kind of error can be really tricky to debug :( but it seems that the error happen in this task : `pcTaskGetTaskName, so try to uncomment/comment parts of your code and maybe allocate more stack to the task.

In my case, I was using a `SSLClient` object in the freertos task, but the tasked crashed before I used it because the task's stack wasn't big enough.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I increased arduino loop() task stack size to 1.5*16384 in main.cpp, but still crash. 
    xTaskCreateUniversal(loopTask, "loopTask", 1.5*16384, NULL, 1, &loopTaskHandle, CONFIG_ARDUINO_RUNNING_CORE);

Comment: sure, appreciate! but I am new here, how to send to you?

Comment: Sorry as I said I am not sure where the problem could be while my IoTLoop() func has over 3K lines so I couldn't post them here. The painful thing is the build works fine when not plugged in the "Dock". After plug into the "Dock", it crashes occasionally.

Comment: Saddly as said in the ESP-IDF doc, memorys leak are very specific and hard to debug, so if you're loop is 3K lines long, I don't think I can help for finding such a specific thing

Comment: Maybe that can help you : https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/heap_debug.html

Comment: I didn't use any malloc or new in my code as I was warned to use them many years ago. The only thing I think could cause RAM issue is the memcpy I used to remove specific words that received and parsed from SIM800 serial. But on the other side I am very confused why plugin to the "Dock" will cause different behavior, providing the power of ESP32 board is still supplied by the PC USB, and the "Dock" is just connecting GPIOs to sensors and LCD.

Comment: a even more wield thing happened today, after couple of crash/reboot, the board suddenly ran the previous build I uploaded!!! why could this be happened?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem.  The root of cause was memory overflow.  I declared a char array of 24, but eventually filled more than 24 char to that array. The keep-rebooting problem was resolved after I increased the size to 128.